# How would I pass in a variable when someone submits a form without changing the URL?

Tags: django

I am trying to pass in a variable when someone submits a form without changing the URL.

Example (views.py):

```
if request.method == "POST":
   # set a variable value
```

Example (index.html):

```
# form here
# when the user clicks submit a modal comes up, I want it to show the variable value in the body
```

Thanks,

**Cameron.**

Comment: What do you mean with "pass a variable"?

Comment: you wan to set a variable(value) to the `request.POST` or just for the `context`?

Comment: Yeah, I want to set a variable to the request.POST.

Comment: `request.POST` object is immutable, so you can't assign it value, what you can do is copy the `data` and add your value to the `copied_data`. ensure this is the `copied_data` passed to your `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using ajax method using JS.